# PHP and HTML: How to put an element between two includes and link it in another page?

Tags: php, html

I'm working with HTML and PHP, but I have a problem. I would like to put different content for each of my pages, but I don't know how. I would like to put a content for my index.php page and a different content for my other pages:

http://prntscr.com/8359bu

and my sign-up.php page: http://prntscr.com/8359l4

I have my container with two breadcrumbs (top and bottom). I want to put my content between the two breadcrumbs and for that, I need to put the content here: http://prntscr.com/835a50

Problem: I want to work on a sign-up.php page and I want to code the register form in the sign-up.php page. But I can't, because I need to have an element that allows me to import the code of my sign-up.php: http://prntscr.com/835bq4 to this location: http://prntscr.com/835a50

Index.php:

```
<?php $title = "Home"; ?>
<?php require "includes/header.php"; ?>
<?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

Header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="body-pusher">
<?php require "includes/navigation.php"; ?>

        <div id="header">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span id="logo">
                    <a href="#">Logo</a>
                </span>
                <div id="visitor-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sign-in">
                            <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="button sign-up" href="sign-up.php">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="breadcrumb-top" class="breadcrumb">
                    <?php include "includes/breadcrumbs.php"; ?>
                </div>

                <div id="breadcrumb-bottom" class="breadcrumb">
                    <?php include "includes/breadcrumbs.php"; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Sign-up.php:

```
<?php $title = "Sign Up"; ?>
<?php require "includes/header.php"; ?>

<?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

Footer.php:

```
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="help.php" class="modal-window-trigger">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="help.php" class="modal-window-trigger">Help</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="copyright">
                    <a href=".">Coded by Dylan - ©2015-2016</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Navigation.php:

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I really need help please.

Comment: For 1 your question is very long and confusing. For 2 you should use javascript instead of php for that

Comment: If you want to put content between the two `div`s, you can move the last breadcrumb into your `footer.php`, wouldn't that solve your issue? Then whatever you put between the two includes will appear where you want it? Also, any particular reason as to why are you using include on one, and require on the other?

Comment: So you're saying that if you put it between the `breadcrumb`s in `header.php` it works, but if you move the last `breadcrumb` to `footer.php` it doesn't work? The code comes in the same order, so why would that not work?

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But there is no better solution?

Comment: Not really. Is this a problem for you, though?

Comment: No, it's not a problem. You think that it's clean to do like this?

Comment: That's really just opinion-based. I do it on my sites, as that works for me - and the code isn't really that messy. If you need another way of doing it, you can put that last `breadcrumb` into a separate file, and `require` it before you `require` the footer.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to solve your issue in the way you want to do. The best solution is to move your `#breadcrumb-bottom` into `footer.php`.

In your case :

header.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="body-pusher">
<?php require "includes/navigation.php"; ?>

        <div id="header">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span id="logo">
                    <a href="#">Logo</a>
                </span>
                <div id="visitor-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sign-in">
                            <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="button sign-up" href="sign-up.php">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="breadcrumb-top" class="breadcrumb">
                    <?php include "includes/breadcrumbs.php"; ?>
                </div>
```

footer.php :

```
                <div id="breadcrumb-bottom" class="breadcrumb">
                    <?php include "includes/breadcrumbs.php"; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="help.php" class="modal-window-trigger">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="help.php" class="modal-window-trigger">Help</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="copyright">
                    <a href=".">Coded by Dylan - ©2015-2016</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sign-up.php :

```
<?php $title = "Sign Up"; ?>
<?php require "includes/header.php"; ?>
<!-- Code here -->
<?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

It's also possible to use JS but I'm not convinced it is a good solution in your case.